# Landing page not appearing on google

Tags: seo, google, landing-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I a have a website which describes every product made by the company and it appears on google, which is fine.
Now i also made a nice landing page, in its own domain, for one product. The page shows a demo video and has a link to the full website that the visitor is supposed to click if he wants to learn more about the product.
The problem is that the page does not have text content, just the video and the link. So Google doesn't know what it is about. I added meta keywords and alt attributes but this didn't help, the page is not listed on the results.
What should i do to make it appear on Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming its had enough time to be discovered (either you submitted it, or its linked to from somewhere) then it sounds like the problem must be that Google doesn't see it has having any real content to speak of, and so it isn't indexing it.

Try adding some text content - Meta keywords isn't widely used, while still worth having for some search engines and 'just in case', don't bank on it.  Meta description is useful.  Better still is some actual text content.

Set yourself up with a [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/webmasters/) account and you'll get some insights into whether your site is being crawled, what googlebot is seeing when it does, etc.  Useful stuff.

Comment: The only solution i can think of is some text in a collapsed div. There are other suggestions in the "What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?" page but they don't apply to a landing page.

Comment: Google can be quite clever about reading CSS and Javascript to determine when content is actually visible.  Lots of black-hat tricks like hidden/collapsed div's and text the same colour as the background, and so on can be ignored or worse, cause you to be de-indexed.